# CodeIgniter como hacer que el id autoincrementable vuelva a insertar desde 1

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hola estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter y en una operación ocurre que debe borrarse todo el contenido de una tabla, y luego insertar los nuevos registros.

Todo esto ocurre sin inconvenientes, pero necesito que al insertarse nuevos registros el id autoincrementable vuelva a insertar desde el 1

Uso MySql como DB

Desde ya muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la instrucción `truncate` *nombre_tabla* en lugar de `delete from` *nombre_tabla*

Comment: Gracias, funcionó inmediatamente